# How to join multiple Model in Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In Django, I have the following models.

```
class Property(models.Model):
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    property_type = models.ForeignKey('PropertyType', models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    geo_info = models.ForeignKey(GeoInfo, models.DO_NOTHING)
    
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['address1', ]),
        ]
        db_table = 'property'

class PropertyType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'property_type'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['name', ]),
        ]

class GeoInfo(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'geo_info'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['zipcode', ]),
            models.Index(fields=['city', ]),
        ]
        
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.zipcode, self.city)
```

I'm trying to use Django REST Framework to serialize **PROPERTY** model as follows.

```
class GeoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GeoInfo
        fields = ['zipcode', 'city', 'state']


class PropertyTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PropertyType

class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    address_geo = GeoSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    prop_type = PropertyTypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['id', 'address1', 'address_geo', 'prop_type']
```

My expected outcome for each item is like

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "address1": "test address",
        "geo_info":{
           "zipcode":"12121",
           "city":"12121",
           "state":"12121",
           },
        "property_type": "unknown",
       
    }
```

and currently, I'm just getting the property data like

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "address1": "test address"
}
```

**So can you help me figure out how to serialize these models?**

Also, it would be great if you can help me how to flatten the outcome and avoid nested node if possible

Comment: use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not clear fully. You asked for no nesting. This may help you -

```
class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    zipcode=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    city=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    state=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ('id','address1','zipcode','city','state','property_type')

    def get_zipcode(self,instance):
        return instance.geo_info.zipcode
    def get_city(self,instance):
        return instance.geo_info.city
    def get_state(self,instance):
        return instance.geo_info.state
```

Comment: Please note that serializer method fields don't have the default validators that belong to the field. It's preferred to use [the source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source).